# How to make words inside of text clickable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, text, cpu-word

I am looking for a solution to make words in a text clickable, I thought about split the text into an array of words and create a btn for each word... but this solution has bad performance... someone has any idea? the text is:

```
const paragraph = 'Emma Woodhouse, handsome, clever, and rich, with a comfortable home and happy disposition, seemed to unite some of the best blessings of existence; and had lived nearly twenty-one years in the world with very little to distress or vex her.'
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a better way of achieving the above, except converting it into an array(for instance, using `Array.from()`), iterating through the sentence, and rendering each character as individually clickable elements.

```
export function App() {
  const paragraph = 'Emma Woodhouse, handsome, clever, and rich, with a comfortable home and happy disposition, seemed to unite some of the best blessings of existence; and had lived nearly twenty-one years in the world with very little to distress or vex her.';

  const handleClick = (word) => {
    console.log(word);
    // handle the rest

  };

  const renderParagraph = () => Array.from(paragraph)
    .map((word) => <span onClick={() => handleClick(word)}>{word}</span>);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {renderParagraph()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a React solution:

```
function clickableWords(paragraph, clickCallback) {
  const words = paragraph.split(/ /g);
  return words.map(w => 
    <span onClick={() => clickCallback(w)}>{w}</span>
  );
}
```

When the word is clicked, `clickCallback` will be called with the word as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to put these words in an html page, your best bet would be to wrap each word in a `<span>` element and attach a click handler to the `<span>`.

e.g.,

```
<span>Emma</span> <span>Woodhouse</span>...
```

and then

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span')).forEach(span => {
 span.addEventListener('click', ...)
})
```

of course there may be a different preferred way to do it using React or other framework or lib.

There are also more perfomant ways to implement this, for example implement a click handler on the `document` which tests for element type.  That way you have only one handler for all elements, rather than one handler for *each* element.

See [AddEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on MDN